# Is it possible to call up a GameScene function within a class/struct instance method?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

So I'm making a game for my computer science class and I made a class named Bomb for the sprites in the game. In the Bomb class, I have a function named blowUp() that is called when a countdown timer for the bomb goes off. When time runs out, the bomb's texture changes among other things, but it should also trigger a game over.

I have a gameOver() function in my GameScene that I want to call up in the blowUp() method but when I do that I get the error message "Instance member 'gameOver' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

Is there any way around this? Thanks in advance

```
class Bomb{
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode()
    var timer = Timer()
    var secondsLeft = 20

    func countDown(){
        secondsLeft -= 1
        if secondsLeft == 0{
           blowUp()
        }
    }

    init {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in self.countDown()})
    }


    func blowUp(){
        self.timer.invalidate()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.sprite.removeFromParent()
        }
       // gameOver() gives me an error

    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get you to do something for me?  I need to tell you.  Works the same way in coding.  You need to find the object and tell them you want a function called.  In your case, you call (scene as! GameScene).gameOver().    Also, almost never use timer in SpriteKit

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the Bomb class doesn't have a `scene` property.

Comment: @0x141E you are right,  I just assumed she extended skspritenode

Comment: I would recommend extending SKSpriteNode instead of having a sprite variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I would make to your code.

1. Extend SKSpriteNode and remove the sprite variable, because you want your bomb to be an actual sprite.

   ```
   class Bomb : SKSpriteNode{
   ```

   ```
   var sprite = SKSpriteNode()
   ```
2. Eliminate your Timer.  Timer goes off of real world, not in game world, so if any external event happens (like a phone call)  your time will be off.  Use SKActions instead.

   ```
   var timer = Timer()
   ```

   var secondsLeft = SKAction.wait(forDuration:20)
3. Remove your countdown function, blowup function and your init, and replace it with an ignite function

   ```
    func countDown(){
        secondsLeft -= 1
        if secondsLeft == 0{
           blowUp()
        }
    }

    init {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in self.countDown()})
    }


    func blowUp(){
        self.timer.invalidate()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.sprite.removeFromParent()
    }
    // gameOver() gives me an error

    }
   ```

   ```
   func ignite() {
          var explosionAnimation = SKAction.animate(with:arrayOfExplosionTextures,timePerFrame:0.1666)
          var blowup = SKAction.run{
                           [unowned self] in
                           (self.scene as GameScene).gameOver()                 
                       }
          //var seq = SKAction.sequence([secondsLeft,explosionAnimation,blowup,SKAction.removeFromParent])
          var seq = SKAction.sequence([secondsLeft,blowup,SKAction.removeFromParent])
       }
   ```

What ignite does is start your bomb when you are ready to start it, waits 30 seconds, then explodes.  This allows you to place bombs on the screen that are delayed or duds.

Here is what your class should look like:

```
    class Bomb : SKSpriteNode{
        var secondsLeft = SKAction.wait(forDuration:20)

        func ignite() {
           //var explosionAnimation = SKAction.animate(with:arrayOfExplosionTextures,timePerFrame:0.1666)
           var blowup = SKAction.run{
                            [unowned self] in
                            (self.scene as GameScene).gameOver()                 
                        }
           //var seq = SKAction.sequence([secondsLeft,explosionAnimation,blowup,SKAction.removeFromParent])
           var seq = SKAction.sequence([secondsLeft,blowup,SKAction.removeFromParent])
        }
    }
```

Here is how you use it in game scene:

```
func placeBomb(x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat){
    let bomb = Bomb(imageNamed:"bomb")
    addChild(bomb)
    bomb.position = CGPoint(x:x,y:y)
    bomb.ignite() 
}
```